# Impossible turn off ssl in menu item

Tags: http, ssl, https, joomla3.0

On my joomla 3.4.3 site I set some menu items to be http, because on them I have wrappers. Before everything was normal, but few times ago I notice that menu items are loading with HTTPS. I control them and settings are ok.

> http://prntscr.com/7tup3d
>   Secure - OFF

Why can this happen? [Link to page](https://carzilla.az/driver/cerime) (this page must be http).